# Short circuit broke a P-channel MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, pcb, current, soldering, short-circuit

I have an electronic board and I inadvertently made a solder bridge while soldering my circuit.

This solder bridge is represented in blue on the picture below.

[image]

After that the P-channel MOSFET surrounded broke.

Its reference is as follows: BSS83PH6327XTSA1

Someone could help me to find the cause of this failure?

Comment: What blue? It's quite hard to see colors in this picture, if there are any. Use red next time; that'd stand out better.

Answer (score 2):

If you place a 10mF cap (the one in the upper right corner) on the p-mos drain, I would imagine that the inrush current while the cap is charging is what broke the MOSFET. That is, the cap is now charged from 15V with nothing but it's own ESR and the 2Ω MOSFET Rds(on) in the way - it is no longer charged through the 47k series resistor.

The part you specified can handle -0.33A continuous drain only.

Comment: sorry for my writing but this cap is 10nF

Comment: However, I have a hypothesis.

At the output of my circuit I have a microcontroller and it breaks because of the 15V that comes out of the bottom mosfet. But if I am not mistaken my soldering bridge will be connected to the ground and there we will have a short circuit. 

This short circuit will create an infinite current and thus break the mosfet.

True or not ?

Comment: @Kolia That's a `m` if I ever saw one. (which would mean a huge aluminium electrolyte or such). And yes if the "3.3V out" drives a MCU then you'll likely fry that MCU first and perhaps the MOSFET next.

Comment: it's because I write in script and not in cursive.

Thank you for your time, but could I have a more detailed description of the physical phenomenon that occurs?

Comment: @Kolia Who knows, it will be specific for every single MCU ever made, pretty much. They all hate high voltages though and usually fry if exposed to one. If the IC turns hot, then you know it's dead. Sometimes if you only provide a high voltage to an I/O pin, you only fry that particular peripheral and the rest of the MCU stays functional. Often some protection diodes burn up/short. But exactly what will happen for any given MCU, nobody knows, unless they happen to know the internals of the MCU.